# Estoy tratando de cuardar una clase de colores en localstorage cuando actualizo la pagina se muestre el color elegido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Llevo dias en este rollo tratando de guardar los colores de la web en localstorage, los datos me muestran de esta manera, adjunto las imagenes.

```
  $(".color-switch").on("click", "button", function() {

    let colors = $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

    localStorage.setItem("color", JSON.stringify(colors));

    if($(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active")) {

        localStorage.getItem("color")

        $("#layoutstyle").attr("href", "views/assets/color/" + $(this).val() + ".css");

    }
    //$("#layoutstyle").attr("href", "views/assets/color/" + $(this).val() + ".css");
    
});



    <div class="color-switch">
      <p>Color Switcher</p>
      <div class="color_box">
        <button value="theme" class="default active"></button>
        <button value="theme-green" class="green"></button>
        <button value="theme-orange" class="orange"></button>
        <button value="theme-lightgreen" class="lightgreen"></button>
        <button value="theme-redpink" class="redpink"></button>
        <button value="theme-lightpurple" class="lightpurple"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

La idea es caprurar los values y almacenarlo en el localstorage

Comment: Por favor quita esas imágenes y pon el código. No es nada cómodo intentar ayduar a alguien que no pone el código porque no podemos copiarlo siquiera para testear algo. No sé qué es exactamente lo que quieres guardar... pero `colors=$(this).addClass()` basicamente te estará guardando una referencia de jQuery... no creo que eso te sirva de mucho al guardar.

Comment: otro metodo para almacenar en localstorage

Comment: El problema no es el método para guardar. Es lo que estás intentando guardar. Si quieres que podamos ayudarte pon todo el código relevante porfavor, eso incluye el html al que haces referencia en ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías de guardar no es el resultado de donde añades la clase active, mas bien tienes que traer el id y almacenarlo,

```
 let colors = $(this).val();
```

Justo como añades el color a tu link.

Y cuando lo traes, creo que debería de ir en tu inicio de pagina, para obtener cual es el botón que se va a mostrar activo.

Te dejo un ejemplo aquí y funcional en [esta liga.](https://playcode.io/662703/), por que desde el sandBox de aquí te generara un error.

```
<div class="color-switch">
        <p>Color Switcher</p>
        <div class="color_box">
            <button value="theme" class="default"></button>
            <button value="theme-green" class="green"></button>
            <button value="theme-orange" class="orange"></button>
            <button value="theme-lightgreen" class="lightgreen"></button>
            <button value="theme-redpink" class="redpink"></button>
            <button value="theme-lightpurple" class="lightpurple"></button>
        </div>
        <a id="layoutstyle"></a>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //En el ready, obtengo el valor que tenga almacenado
    let color = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("color"));
    if (color) {
        //Si hay algun valor selecciono el boton con ese valor
        $(".color_box button[value='" + color + "']").addClass("active");
        $("#layoutstyle").attr("href", "views/assets/color/" + color + ".css");
        $("#layoutstyle").text("views/assets/color/" + color + ".css");
    } else {
        //Si no selecciono el default
        $(".color_box button[value='theme']").addClass("active");
    }
});

$(".color-switch").on("click", "button", function () {

    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    let colors = $(this).val();

    localStorage.setItem("color", JSON.stringify(colors));

    $("#layoutstyle").attr("href", "views/assets/color/" + colors + ".css");
    $("#layoutstyle").text("views/assets/color/" + colors + ".css");

});
```

```
.color_box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}
button{
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button.active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px rgb(100, 124, 241);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px rgb(100, 124, 241);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px rgb(100, 124, 241);
}
button.default{
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
button.green{
    background-color: green;
}
button.orange{
    background-color: orange;
}
button.lightgreen{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
button.redpink{
    background-color: #ff99cc;
}
button.lightpurple{
    background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

Comment: Gracias master me funciono.